# Spring Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xml-parsing, nsxmlnode

I am new in spring and I am trying to construct the object using Spring Container which shall parse my XML file, so I have one `.xml` and two `.java` class.

Spring version 5.1.0

I was looking into similar solution but some are maven solution not for spring.

1. employeeBeanFile.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <bean id="emp" class="co.bin.rito.Employee">
       <property name="eid" value="143529" />
       <property name="ename" value="Rito Sarkar" />
       <property name="eaddress" value="Tower Two Magarpatta, S5-458" />
   </bean>
   ```
2. Employee.java

   ```
   public class Employee {
       // this contains attributes 
       // constructor and methods
       // and set, get and toString() function 
   }
   ```
3. Client.java

   ```
   import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
   import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
   import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

   public class Client {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // Spring way | IOC (Inversion of control)
           ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("employeeBeanFile.xml");
           Employee e = (Employee) context.getBean("emp");
           System.out.println("Employee one details: " + e);
           ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();
       }}
   ```

**With this code i am getting below error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:573)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at co.bin.rito.Client.main(Client.java:11)
```

Comment: What does your pom look like for spring dependencies?

Comment: This error occurs if you are mixing jars from different version of a framework, in this case Spring. Check your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due the jars from different version in Spring. please use the correct jars dependency in your pom . Also make sure you are not including the other version of jars in your build path .